# finding a file which was modified in last 10 minutes

Tags: bash, find

I am running this command to find out the files which were modified in last 10 minutes

```
 find / -fstype local -mtime -10m
```

but it is giving following error each time

```
find: missing argument to `-mtime'
```

What is wrong with above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is `-mmin` like

```
find / -fstype local -mmin -10
```

Answer (score 3):

Use mmin instead of mtime which is only for hours.

```
$ find / -fstype local -mmin -10
```

Answer (score 2):

Gnu find seems to want -mtime argument as days

```
File’s  data was last modified n*24 hours ago.
```

See **-mmin**